# Multiselect option with remove button cannot remove the items

Tags: jquery, html

**Select numbers (you can select each number any number of times):**

```
<select name="number_selection" method="post" id="number_selection" >
   <option value="0">0</option>
   <option value="1">1 </option>
   <option value="2">2</option>
   <option value="3">3</option>
   <option value="4">4</option>
   <option value="5">5</option>
 </select>
 <input type="button" value="Select" id="select_button"/> 


  <div id="feedback"> </div>
```

**This is the jquery i've written to select and deselect:**

```
 $('#select_button').click(function(){
var gs= $('#number_selection').val();
$('#feedback').append(gs + '  ' + '<input type="button" value="Remove" id="gs_remove" />' + '<br>');

});

$('#gs_remove').click(function(){
(this).remove();
});
```

**I am able to select the options, but cannot remove the options using the Remove button. Please help**

Comment: There is a `$` missing before `(this).remove();`

Comment: the code is not working even with the $

Comment: Are you adding buttons with the same id? That won't really work. In any case, 'click' is not enough.  use `.on('click')` to attach handlers to elements added to the DOM later

Comment: yeah. but this code is working........   $('#select_button').click(function(){
   var gs= $('#number_selection').val();
   $('#feedback').append('<span>' + gs + '</span>' + '  ' + '<input type="button" value="Remove" class="gs_remove" />' + '<br>');        but i've got another problem with that. After removing span, i'm losing the space, when i select the option again, its getting appended in the next line, not at the same place the option i removed. 
});

$('#feedback').on('click','.gs_remove',function(){
   $(this).prev('span').remove();
   $(this).remove();  // use '$' in selector
});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of **repeating id(gs_remove) repeat class** and use **event delegation** and enclose the `#number_selection` value inside `span` as shown :-

```
$('#select_button').click(function(){
   var gs= $('#number_selection').val();
   $('#feedback').append('<span>' + gs + '</span>' + '  ' + '<input type="button" value="Remove" class="gs_remove" />' + '<br>');
});

$('#feedback').on('click','.gs_remove',function(){
   $(this).prev('span').remove();
   $(this).next('br').remove();
   $(this).remove();  // use '$' in selector
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q70mo5sq/1/)

When you are appending some data inside `#feedback` you are repeating buttons with **id's `gs_remove`** which is incorrect you cannot have more than one element on page with same `id` so instead use `class` as shown above.

Comment: its working, but i've got another problem with that. After removing span, i'm losing the space, when i select the option again, its getting appended in the next line, not at the same place the option i removed. Did you get my point ?

Comment: it worked, thank you. One more question, please don't mind, What should I do if i want to assign different class/id to the options after selecting them ?

Comment: @SalauddinFarhaan....bind a change event on `#number_selection` and then generate a random no with javascript and assign the random no to currently selected option as `$(this).attr('class',randomno)`

Comment: Can you please help me with that, i am new to his, and i dont understand much things

Comment: @SalauddinFarhaan...it will be good if you post a new question on stackoverflow describing what exactly you want because it will be difficult for me to give answer in comments section.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need these code below

You can also using .on in jQuery to add event to new element

I'm using onclick event to call a javascript function

```html
<select name="number_selection" id="number_selection" >
        <option value="0">0</option>
        <option value="1">1 </option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
    </select>
    <input type="button" value="Select" id="select_button"/>


    <div id="feedback"> </div>

    <script>
        function removeMe(obj){
            $(obj).parent().remove();
        }

        $('#select_button').click(function(){
            var gs= $('#number_selection').val();
            $('#feedback').append('<div>' + gs + '  ' + '<input type="button" value="Remove" onclick="removeMe(this);"/>' + '<br></div>');

        });

    </script>
```

Using jQuery instead of onclick event in remove button

```html
<select name="number_selection" id="number_selection" >
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="1">1 </option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
</select>
<input type="button" value="Select" id="select_button"/>


<div id="feedback"> </div>

<script>

    $('#feedback').on('click', '.remove-button', function(){
        $(this).parent().remove();
    });


    $('#select_button').click(function(){
        var gs= $('#number_selection').val();
        $('#feedback').append('<div>' + gs + '  ' + '<input type="button" value="Remove" class="remove-button"/>' + '<br></div>');

    });

</script>
```